# Jcache integration in hazelcast does not work

Tags: caching, hazelcast, jcache

I am currently trying to integrate HazelCast cache with jcache objects, to base my developments on its standard.

I need to integrate a large number of different configurations, for this I created a hazelcast.xml. Where I've tried with hazelcast map objects (com.hazelcast.core.IMap), I get it working so I can get the cache with the appropriate configuration:

```
private static void initHazelcast() {
        log.info("initHazelcast()");

        Config cfg = null;
        try {
            cfg = new XmlConfigBuilder("./src/main/resources/hazelcast.xml").build();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);

        IMap map = hazelcastInstance.getMap("EXPIR00001");

        log.info("initHazelcast() End");
    }
```

HazelCast.xml:

```
<hazelcast  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.9.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config">
  <map name="EXPIR00001">
    <time-to-live-seconds>1</time-to-live-seconds>
    <max-idle-seconds>1</max-idle-seconds>
    <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
    <max-size policy="PER_NODE">5000</max-size>
  </map>
</hazelcast>
```

Now I try to use the class javax.cache.Cache of JCache.

I'm using this example, but I do not retrieve the xml configuration like this:

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.3/manual/html-single/index.html#jcache-declarative-configuration
and
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.3/manual/html-single/index.html#scoping-to-join-clusters

Hazelcast.xml:

```
<hazelcast  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.9.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config">

    <cache name="EXPIR00001">
      <backup-count>1</backup-count>
      <async-backup-count>1</async-backup-count>
      <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
      <eviction size="10000" max-size-policy="ENTRY_COUNT" eviction-policy="LRU" />
       <expiry-policy-factory>
                    <timed-expiry-policy-factory expiry-policy-type="CREATED"
                                                    duration-amount="1"
                                                    time-unit="DAYS"/>
       </expiry-policy-factory>
    </cache>

</hazelcast>
```

method java:

```
private static void initHazelcast() {
        log.info("initHazelcast()");

        Config cfg = null;
        try {
            cfg = new XmlConfigBuilder("./src/main/resources/hazelcast.xml").build();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);

        CacheManager manager = Caching.getCachingProvider().getCacheManager();
        //In JCache
        Cache<byte[], byte[]> cache = manager.getCache( "EXPIR00001" );

        log.info("initHazelcast() End");
    }
```

CacheManager manager how can you relate to the hazelcast intance ??.The manager object does not retrieve the cache Id = "EXPIR00001"

I need to configure from an xml file, decalratively (Hazelcast.xml). There are many configurations, which we may need.

I can not use:
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.3/manual/html-single/index.html#hazelcast-jcache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, My intention was to leave manager as a static variable in a class.

```
CacheManager manager = Caching.getCachingProvider().getCacheManager();
```

replace this line with:

```
CachingProvider caching = Caching.getCachingProvider();
CacheManager cacheManager = caching.getCacheManager();
```

Complete example :
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.3/manual/html-single/index.html#scoping-to-join-clusters

Answer (score 0):

Here is the first sample code at http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.3/manual/html-single/index.html#hazelcast-jcache

```
// Retrieve the CachingProvider which is automatically backed by
// the chosen Hazelcast member or client provider
CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider();

// Create a CacheManager
CacheManager cacheManager = cachingProvider.getCacheManager();

// Create a simple but typesafe configuration for the cache
CompleteConfiguration<String, String> config =
    new MutableConfiguration<String, String>()
        .setTypes( String.class, String.class );

// Create and get the cache
Cache<String, String> cache = cacheManager.createCache( "example", config );
// Alternatively to request an already existing cache
// Cache<String, String> cache = cacheManager
//     .getCache( name, String.class, String.class );

// Put a value into the cache
cache.put( "world", "Hello World" );

// Retrieve the value again from the cache
String value = cache.get( "world" );

// Print the value 'Hello World'
System.out.println( value );
```

And the explanation of how Hazelcast integration of JCache works:

> First of all, we retrieve the javax.cache.spi.CachingProvider using
>   the static method from javax.cache.Caching:: getCachingManager, which
>   automatically picks up Hazelcast as the underlying JCache
>   implementation, if available in the classpath. This way, the Hazelcast
>   implementation of a CachingProvider will automatically start a new
>   Hazelcast member or client (depending on the chosen provider type) and
>   pick up the configuration from either the command line parameter or
>   from the classpath. We will show how to use an existing
>   HazelcastInstance later in this chapter; for now, we keep it simple.

I suggest you please go through the documentation, you will find answers to lot of your questions.

Comment: I already know that solution. I need to configure from an xml file, decalratively (Hazelcast.xml). There are many configurations, which we may need.

Comment: Here is a code sample for declarative configuration: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/blob/master/jcache/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/examples/declarative/DeclarativeConfigurationTest.java

Comment: I'm using this example, but I do not retrieve the xml configuration like this:

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.3/manual/html-single/index.html#jcache-declarative-configuration and http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.3/manual/ html-single / index.html # scoping-to-join-clusters


That's not the problem